# for loop to generate and save multiple ggplots in a separate file

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data (TransDat70) contains 103 variables total. The first 102 are named "V1" through "V102", the last variable is names "Time.Min".

I need to generate 102 ggplots of each variable (V1 through V102) against the variable "Time.Min". I then need to save all these ggplots in a separate file (pdf) preferably all next to/below one another for comparison purposes.

I tried using code that I was able to find online but none has worked for me so far.

Here is my code:

```
var_list = combn(names(TransDat70)[1: 102], 2, simplify = FALSE)
plot_list = list()

for (i in 1: 3) {
    p = ggplot(TransDat70, aes_string(x = var_list[[i]][1], y = var_list[[i]][2])) + geom_point()
    plot_list[[i]] = p
}

for (i in 1: 3) {
    plot70 = paste("iris_plot_", i, ".tiff", sep = "")
    tiff(plot70)
    print(plot_list[[i]])
    dev.off()
}

pdf("plots.pdf")

for (i in 1: 3) {
    print(plot_list[[i]])
}

dev.off()
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If by separate you meant each plot in a separate file, how about this?

```
library(ggplot2)

# FAKE DATA AS EXAMPLE
TransDat70 <- data.frame(
  1:10,
  1:10,
  1:10,
  1:10,
  1:10
)

colnames(TransDat70) <- c('V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4', 'Time.Min')

for (i in 1:(length(TransDat70) - 1)) {
  p <- ggplot(TransDat70, aes_string(x = paste('V', toString(i), sep=''), y='Time.Min')) + geom_point()
  ggsave(paste('~/Desktop/plot_', i, '.pdf', sep=''), p)
}
```

See the [`ggsave`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/ggsave.html) documentation for more options.

If you meant to have them all in one big file, take a look at [Printing multiple ggplots into a single pdf, multiple plots per page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234248/printing-multiple-ggplots-into-a-single-pdf-multiple-plots-per-page).

However, for that many plots it would make a likely make a huge file, which could be problematic to open, especially if you have many points in your plots. In that case it might be better to compare them as separate files.