# Multiple plots gives a blank PDF, data dimension error

Tags: r, pdf, save

I have an error when trying to plot multiple plots to a PDF. I have used the code from [Printing multiple ggplots into a single pdf, multiple plots per page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234248/printing-multiple-ggplots-into-a-single-pdf-multiple-plots-per-page) to create my loop, but I am not sure what is causing the error.

The PDF compiles, but it’s just one 1 page and its blank. I have recreated the problem below and it seems like a data dimension issue, but it’s not clear to me how it should be resolved. The plots can be saved manually to PDF from the plot viewer, but it seems to fall over in the loop. My expectation is to get a PDF that's 3 pages long with one chart per page.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(naniar)
library(visdat)
library(gridExtra)

p = list()

head(iris)

p[[1]] = gg_miss_var(iris) 
p[[2]] = vis_miss(iris)
p[[3]] = vis_dat(iris)

pdf("plots_test2.pdf", onefile = TRUE)
for (i in seq(length(p))) {
  do.call("grid.arrange", p[[i]])  
}
dev.off()
```

The error that comes up:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "wrapvp", value = list(x = 0.5, y = 0.5,  : 
  replacement has 17 rows, data has 5
```

Comment: If you delete the `pdf` and `dev.off`` lines, does just the loop work? Seems like we could narrow down the problem to related to (a) producing the plots (you say this works from the viewer), (b) producing the plots in a loop (seems likely source of problems...) (c) putting the plots in a pdf.

Comment: Well spotted - the loop does not work. When I delete `pdf` and `dev.off()`, I get the error. So now I suppose it has to do with the `grid.arrange` call

Comment: I'd suggest editing your question then to focus on printing these plots in a loop rather than generating a pdf. That said, I'm not familiar with the non-ggplot packages you're using, but in the question you point to `p` is a list where each item is a sublist of multiple plots, that need `grid.arrange` to be displayed together. Is that your case too? If `gg_miss_var` and `vis_miss` give single plots, and `print(p[[1]])` works to display the first plot, then forget the `do.call` and just put `print(p[[i]])` in the for loop.

Comment: Boom - this works! Thank you. Replaced `do.call` with `print()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `do.call` and `grid.arrange` with `print()`

Each plot saves to a single page in the PDF

```
pdf("plots_test2.pdf", onefile = TRUE)
for (i in seq(length(p))) {
   print(p[[i]])  
}
dev.off()
```