# issue using patchwork with gridExtra to save plots across multiple pages

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra, patchwork

I have a list of objects created with `patchwork`. I'd like to save each element of this list as a separate page within a single PDF.

If doing this for ordinary `ggplot2` objects I would combine the plots using `gridExtra::marrangeGrob()`, as per the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61532087/5483273). I like this approach because it's tidy, and because the output includes page numbers.

However I cannot get this approach to work with `patchwork`. Instead of printing the entire plot 'composite' on each page, it only shows one of the plot elements. MWE given below.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
library(gridExtra)

# dummy plots
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_line()

# create plot 'composites' using `patchwork` and combine into list
# elements duplicated for simplicity
plot_list <- list(
  wrap_plots(p1, p2),
  wrap_plots(p1, p2)
)

# attempt to export with separate page for each list element
# expect to produce a PDF with two pages, both of which show p1 adjacent to p2
plot_list %>%
  marrangeGrob(nrow = 1, ncol = 1) %>% # no combination of nrow and ncol seems to work
  ggsave(filename = "plots.pdf")
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is combining `patchwork` with `gridExtra` a silly idea? If so, what's the better alternative?

Comment: It seems to work with `cowplot::plot_grid` instead of `wrap_plots`, but I'm not sure if this is flexible enough for you.

Comment: Does something like this work? 
`pdf("myplots.pdf")
   for (i in 1:2){
        plot(plots_for_page[i])
}
dev.off()`